# Look ahead in regular expression

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g, regex-lookarounds

Is there something such as look-ahead, look-behind in Oracle's regular expression such as `?<=` in some languages ?

For example we want to look for "ef" only if before it is "ab" and not "cd".

In `REGEXP_REPLACE` we can do this by refering to the nth group but how about `REGEXP_INSTR` and `REGEXP_SUBSTR` ?

Example: look for position of *ef* if it is a *abef* and not when it is a *cdef*. I know for this example, we can look for *abef* and offset by 2, but this is a simple case. Some times it is not possible to offset. I don't have a good scenario at hand but let's say : Look for *ef* on ly if before it is 2 to 5 times  of the following characters a or b or 2 ([ab2]){2,5}

Comment: If it is before `ab` then it cannot be before `cd`.

Comment: _before IT is ab and not cd_.

Comment: [Oracle regex flavor is POSIX](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm#i1007663), it does not support lookarounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> look for "ef" only if before it is "ab" and not "cd"

If before it is `ab` then before it cannot be `cd` so you can just do:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE( text, '(ab)ef', '\1XX' )
```

or

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR( text, 'ab(ef)', 1, 1, NULL, 1 )
```

or

```
REGEXP_INSTR( text, 'abef', 1, 1, 1, NULL ) - LENGTH( 'ef' )
```

> Look for ef on ly if before it is 2 to 5 times of the following characters a or b or 2 `([ab2]){2,5}`

```
REGEXP_REPLACE( ly, '([ab2]{2,5})ef', '\1XX' )
```

or

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR( ly, '[ab2]{2,5}(ef)', 1, 1, NULL, 1 )
```

or

```
REGEXP_INSTR( ly, '[ab2]{2,5}ef', 1, 1, 1, NULL ) - LENGTH( 'ef' )
```

> looking for [efg]{4,6} only if before it is [ab2]{2,5}

```
REGEXP_REPLACE( ly, '([ab2]{2,5})[efg]{4,6}', '\1XX' )
```

or

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR( ly, '[ab2]{2,5}([efg]{4,6})', 1, 1, NULL, 1 )
```

or

```
REGEXP_INSTR( ly, '[efg]{4,6}', REGEXP_INSTR( ly, '[ab2]{2,5}[efg]{4,6}' ) )
```

Comment: Are you sure this is Oracle ? _REGEXP_SUBSTR_ has maximum 5 parameters. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm
Besides, how about looking for _[efg]{4,6}_ only if before it is _[ab2]{2,5}_

Comment: @Kenny Oracle 11g (which you tagged in the question) takes an extra argument - the index of the sub-group to return. See the [Oracle 11g `REGEXP_SUBSTR` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm)